# How to align a zoomed checkbox with a label

Tags: css

I have the following html which renders the following

```
<input type="checkbox" class='btn-filter' style='zoom:2; id="inactive-accounts" name="" value="1">
<label style= 'font-size:15px' for="inactive-accounts">Show Inactive Accounts</label><br>
```

[image]

If the checkbox is a regular size the text lines up well with the checkbox but since I am using zoom to increase the size of the checkbox it is not aligned correctly. I tried a solution I found on stack overflow to create CSS like so:

```
    .checkboxes label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.checkboxes input {
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom:"2"
}

.checkboxes label span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<input type="checkbox" class='btn-filter' style='zoom:2; justify-content:center' id="inactive-accounts" name="" value="1">
<label style= 'font-size:15px' for="inactive-accounts">Show Inactive Accounts</label><br>
```

but this does not fix the issue. Could it be that I should not be using zoom to increase the size of the checkbox here?

Answer (score 2):

I highly discourage using the property ZOOM. To increase the element, it is better to use - transform.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

```css
.checkboxes {
    outline: 1px solid green;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.checkboxes input, .checkboxes label {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.checkboxes label {
    white-space: nowrap;
        margin-left: 7px;
        outline: 1px solid grey;
        padding-left: 5px;
}
.checkboxes input {
        transform: scale(2);
        outline: 1px solid grey;
}
.checkboxes label span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="inactive-accounts" name="" value="1">
    <label for="inactive-accounts">Show Inactive Accounts</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you free to wrap your elements in a `div` or "container" element? If so, you can set `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` onto that element, which would align your input and label.

Here's a snippet showing both a regular and zoomed checkbox alongside a label.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class='btn-filter' style='zoom:2; justify-content:center' id="inactive-accounts" name="" value="1">
  <label style='font-size:15px' for="inactive-accounts">Show Inactive Accounts</label>
</div>
<br>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class='btn-filter' style='zoom:1; justify-content:center' id="inactive-accounts-2" name="" value="1">
  <label style='font-size:15px' for="inactive-accounts-2">Show Inactive Accounts</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @MisterJojo - what do you mean? The snippet shows the OP's original HTML with the enlarged checkbox, as well as a version where the zoom is the regular size.

Comment: The OP isn't looking for an "effect". I think you've misinterpreted his question. He states, "If the checkbox is a regular size the text lines up well with the checkbox but since I am **using zoom to increase the size of the checkbox** it is not aligned correctly."

Comment: perhaps I'm not understanding you then because my snippet doesn't have an "effect" either. It merely shows alignment when a checkbox has no zoom, and also when it has a zoom, which the OP mentioned. He said when he tried without zoom, it was aligned, but with zoom, it wasn't aligned, so I aimed to show that both scenarios work in my snippet. Either way, I appreciate your comments.